# React unique key prop error when trying to render two adjacent tr elements via map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stumped. I'm trying to get rid of a unique key prop error specifically:

`index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
 Check the render method of`SavingsGoalList`. in Fragment (created by SavingsGoalList)`

SavingsGoalList is this component where I'm trying to render a tr with standard table data and a second adjacent tr where a progress bar is shown based on user input.

The keys are in fact unique so I think the issue is these adjacent tags. Any insight? Thanks!

```
<tbody>
  {props.savings.length > 0 ? (
    props.savings.map(saving => (
    <>
    <tr key={saving.id}>
      <td>{saving.item}</td>
      <td>{saving.goal}</td>
      <td>{saving.savedAmount}</td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={() => props.editSavingsGoal(saving)}>Edit</button>
        <button onClick={() => props.deleteSavingsGoal(saving.id)}>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr key={saving.savingGoalId}>
      <td colSpan={4}><progress max={saving.goal} value={saving.savedAmount}/></td>
    </tr>
    </>
  ))
) : (
  <tr>
    <td colSpan={3}>No Savings Goals</td>
  </tr>
)}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<>` means `<React.Fragment>`

`key` attribute should be in outermost tag.

`<React.Fragment key={saving.id}>` use like this